# How to use a variable of $.post() function into another in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am setting a variable using POST() method in jQuery when my document is ready. Now i want to use that variable in another function, how can i do that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('count_products.php',function(data){
    var count_products = data;
    });
});
```

Now i want to use that count_products variable in another function which executes on focusout event. I can not access it's value as it has a limited scope upto its own function only. What is the solution?

I have read lots of the post on stackoverflow which defines different way to pass the variable by creating a function and returning its value etc.
But no solution is efficient in its way.

What is the best practice you do?

Comment: Thinking out loud here, but what if you instantiate the variable at the very beginning of the script: var count_products = null;.  And then in your $,post function, simply change the value of it?

Comment: You could make count_products a global variable.

Comment: Altaf you can use, a global, you can use .ajaxSuccess( handler ) http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/, and you can also use the pub/sub  pattern to do what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the variable with global scope:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var count_products = 0;
    $.post('count_products.php',function(data){
    count_products = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count_products;
    $.post('count_products.php',function(data){
    count_products = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've done what you need done.  Check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iateyourkitten/9c343kfm/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var products = "initial string";

$(document).on('click', '#set_var', function(){
    products = 'button was clicked';
});

$(document).on('click', '#get_var', function(){
    alert(products);
});
});
```